# Extract dateTime from Google Calendar with different Format

Tags: python, datetime, format, google-calendar-api, extract

My problem is the OutPut that Google Calendar's code gives me.
If I tell my program to output the next 10 events in a label he shows me only the last (ins't the problem itself though) like :

`Event YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.Z` which would be okay, but I **need** it to look something like:

`Event DD MM` (preferably formatted as ('%a %d') 'cause the year is obvious).

***WHAT I KNOW***

In google's code is this:

```
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
```

the problem occurs (I think) in the  `.get('dateTime'`
I did a `print (events)` and besides a bunch of useless code I got this: `'start': {'dateTime': '2018-04-03T15:30:00+02:00'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2018-04-03T16:30:00+02:00'}`. Supposedly when I print the events I print that section of 'dateTime' as it's written there.

Now, how do I tell python to print **ONLY** the ninth, tenth, sixth and seventh character from the dateTime he extracts?

If any clarification is needed please tell me.

Comment: Google calendar returns your date as as string its your job to format it as you see fit.  if it helps the string formatting is formatted according to [RFC3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339)

Comment: In that case I think you could say that, didn't really know myself what I was asking, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Google APis can be a bit confusing.  Just remember everything is returned to you as a string.  Makes it easier for you to format it later :)